# How to add action to "done" button keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

[image]

I have a quiz. I want to go to the next question was carried out using the "done" button on the keyboard. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by add this Line for set Type of return key type :

```
 txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

and for handle action you can do like this :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    // you can handle here
    return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement delegate of texfield named textfield should return an add code to show your next question. And if you have requirement such like that for each question keyboard should be open, then your code could  be like this, first you have to resignfirst responder and your next quiz question become the first responder and so on.